# Get the earliest date per row

Tags: r, date, dataframe, max, min

I have a data frame of different patients suffering from cancer and dates of different recurrences like:

```
Pat-ID DAT_LOCAL_REC DAT_INTRANS_MET DAT_LYMPH_MET DAT_VIS_MET DAT_LAST_OBS
1      2016-08-01    NA              NA            NA           2017-01-30
2      NA            NA              2015-09-15    NA           2017-01-30
3      2016-07-30    NA              2015-10-10    2016-07-30   2017-01-30
```

To calculate progression free survival I need the first date of any recurrence for each patient. I tried it with "apply" but was not able to get the result. How can I handle NAs. Any ideas?

Comment: `apply(df, 1, min, na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: This fixes my problems with the NA values, Thank you!